# ProgressBar on Windows Phone 7 is not disappearing

Tags: windows-phone-7

If I now look at the problem this way. The XAML code is as follow:

```
<toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar 
                        x:Name="performanceProgressBar" 
                        Margin="0,-40,0,0" 
                        IsIndeterminate="true" 
                        Visibility="{Binding ShowProgressBar}" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

and the code behind is as follows:

```
private bool ShowProgressBar
{
    get { return !App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded; }
}
```

The progress bar does not disappear after the data has been loaded, i.e. ShowProgressBar is false.

Comment: Doesn't "visibility" have to be either "visible" or "collapsed"? It has been a while, so I could be wrong, but I don't think it takes a true/false value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```
IsIndeterminate="{Binding ShowProgressBar}"
```

Comment: Yes, you can't leave it `Indeterminate` even if it is not visible